# Determine the Distribution (self-study)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

During my study, I ended up with the following distribution below. Is this a variant of a known distribution type? It is over semi-bounded support.

\begin{equation}
p(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-1\right)}{x^2}
\end{equation}

I have tried to match it to several distributions but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: this seems a density of a random variable, not a distribution. You can simplify it as $f(x)=x^{-2}\left(1-e^{-x^2/2}\right)$

Comment: It is the density of a random variable. My question is if it is a distribution that is recognizable.

Comment: Did you actually check it is a valid density, I.e. does it integrate to 1?